# Question web part

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I'm a newbie to SharePoint development.

I have a task to develop a web part with the functionality of a questionnaire.

The administrator creates a questionnaire. Then the users fill in the questions. Later, the administrator can access the results for each user and build some reports from it.

It is difficult for me to imagine how to realize such functionality in WSS.

Can you show me the way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You say you cannot use a 'Survey' as your needs are special.  What is limiting your use of this?  This might help the community suggest appropriate alternatives.

Answer (score 6):

Well, there is a [built-in feature, called Survey](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA102085781033.aspx), that does exactly what you described.

Depending on your needs you could still use Survey web part but create your own custom logic to fill or display survey results.

The third option might for filling surveys might be Infopath. Check [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/infopath/archive/2007/01/24/survey-creator.aspx) for ideas. Please note: Special licensing applies to Infopath and Infopath Forms Services and you might not have this licensed. It is a bit complicated and it is out of scope for this question.

Comment: Thank you much! I couldn't use this feature as is, becouse my survey is special. But it is good as example.

Comment: Well depending on your needs you could still use Survey web part but create your own custom logic to fill or display survery results.

Comment: There's also Infopath.  I've used it to make surveys for sharepoint.

Comment: @Brian: +1, I will be adding your answer to my post and make it a commmunity wiki.